# aggregate by consecutive values and group

Tags: r, sequence

In the following data set I have filtered JSON intervals by instances where the bike count is equal to zero.  `station_summary_id` represents one time interval and increases by consecutive integers (in the example you see that 64129 is associated with "2014-10-01 07:00:00", then 64130 is associated with "2014-10-01 07:10:00" , and so on. `station_id` is the unique id of a station.

My objective is:  to find the longest chain of consecutive integers by `station_id` -in other words - to find out the longest time period that each station was empty.  I understand that this requires grouping first by `station_id` and then counting the longest consecutive sequence in `station_summary_id` but am not sure how to automate this for all station ids.

```
> dim(data)
[1] 307039      7


> head(data)
      station_id status available_bike_count          created_at station_summary_id month year
13694          2 Active                    0 2014-10-01 07:00:00              64129    10 2014
13702         10 Active                    0 2014-10-01 07:00:00              64129    10 2014
13706         14 Active                    0 2014-10-01 07:00:00              64129    10 2014
13710         18 Active                    0 2014-10-01 07:00:00              64129    10 2014
13713         21 Active                    0 2014-10-01 07:00:00              64129    10 2014
13728         36 Active                    0 2014-10-01 07:00:00              64129    10 2014
```

reproducible example:

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(station_id = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Active", class = "factor"), available_bike_count = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), station_summary_id = c(64129L, 
64130L, 64131L, 64132L, 64133L, 64134L, 64136L, 64138L, 64139L, 
64140L, 64141L, 64142L, 64143L, 64144L, 64145L, 64146L, 64147L, 
64148L, 64149L, 64150L, 64152L, 64161L, 64162L, 64170L, 64273L, 
64322L, 64324L, 64341L, 64884L, 64886L, 64896L, 64897L, 64898L, 
64899L, 64900L, 64901L, 64902L, 64903L, 64904L, 64905L, 64906L, 
64907L, 64908L, 64909L, 64910L, 64911L, 64912L, 64913L, 64917L, 
64918L, 65214L, 65219L, 66314L, 66439L, 66450L, 66583L, 66587L, 
66589L, 66600L, 66872L, 66880L, 67037L, 67048L, 82854L, 82855L, 
82856L, 82857L, 82858L, 82859L, 82860L, 82861L, 82862L, 82863L, 
82867L, 82868L), month = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L), year = c(2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L)), .Names = c("station_id", 
"status", "available_bike_count", "station_summary_id", "month", 
"year"), row.names = c(NA, -75L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your example is not complete. You must add the output that you are expecting from the example. What output would you consider the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

See `?rle` for better understanding of possible uses of run length encoding.

With your new data:

```
> max( rle( diff(dat$station_summary_id) )$lengths )
[1] 12
```

With multiple station_id's in the revised example, I found that `aggregate` worked fairly well:

```
 aggregate( dat$station_summary_id, dat['station_id'], FUN= function(d) max( rle( diff(d) )$lengths ) )
#---------
  station_id  x
1          2 12
2          3 17
3          4  9
```

This also succeed with data.table syntax:

```
dat <- setDT(dat)
dat[,   max( rle( diff(station_summary_id) )$lengths ) , by='station_id']
#-----
   station_id V1
1:          2 12
2:          3 17
3:          4  9
```

Comment: thanks, but `nrow` wouldn't solve the problem. I need to count the maximum number of consecutive integers, and also, to count the amount of times that there are more than six consecutive integers (the amount of times that a station was empty for more than one hour).  I have subset the data by one `station_id` above.  As you can see not all values in the  `station_summary_id` column are consecutive.  I tried the above code but the output was 2, which is incorrect

Comment: Can you see why I find that saying that an answer is "not correct" without saying what you consider to be the right answer is rather off-putting?

Comment: However, when I use this code on the whole dataset, I cannot tell which values belong to which `station_id`, it just produces a long list

Comment: For tested code, one needs to provide an example of sufficient complexity.  Presumably you would use aggregate or `lapply( split( , ), fun)` or some other strategy for iterating over the separate station_id's.

Comment: I have included a more complex dataframe above

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr`, `data.table`, or `base R` to find the max duration by station id. See @42's mention of the function `rle` at the center of the calls:

```
#dplyr
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(station_id) %>% 
  summarise(with(rle(station_summary_id), values[which.max(lengths)]))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,list(with(rle(station_summary_id),
               values[which.max(lengths)])),by=station_id]

#base R
lapply(split(data$station_summary_id, data$station_id), 
       function(x) with(rle(x), values[which.max(lengths)]))
```

**edit**

With the new data:

```
dt[,with(rle(diff(station_summary_id) > 1), max(lengths[!values])), by=station_id]
```

Comment: thanks, but these codes do not produce an output of the sum the maximum number of consecutive integers in `station_summary_id` per station.  I added some data above to clarify (I subset by one `station_id`)

Comment: this works for the example above, but when I try it on the entire dataset, I receive the following error: `Error in `[.data.table`(data, , with(rle(diff(station_summary_id) > 1),  : 
  Column 1 of result for group 434 is type 'double' but expecting type 'integer'. Column types must be consistent for each group.
In addition: Warning message:
In max(lengths[!values]) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: Your data is not in the format that you show in your question. I don't have your data. How would you like me to fix something that I can't see? You asked how is it done and I showed you the framework. Are you expecting me to finish your project for you?

Comment: If you are unwilling to post the actual variability in your data I can't magically insert myself into your computer. You are not hiring me to compete work for you. You asked can it be done and the answer is yes. Please take the time to troubleshoot the application of the solution that works for the data you presented.

Comment: My apologies, I have included a more variable dataframe above.

Comment: Your example is not complete. You must add the output that you are expecting from the example. What output would you consider the right answer. You should not "write" it out, instead post the actual output that should result from the example.