# keep only consecutive observations

Tags: r, dataframe

As said in the title, I have a data.frame like below,

```
df<-data.frame('id'=c('1','1','1','1','1','1','1'),'time'=c('1998','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2007'))
df
  id time
1  1 1998
2  1 2000
3  1 2001
4  1 2002
5  1 2003
6  1 2004
7  1 2007
```

there are some others cases with shorter or longer time window than this,just for illustration's sake.

I want to do two things about this data set, first, find all those `id` that have **at least** five consecutive observations here, this can be done by following solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302831/aggregate-by-consecutive-values-and-group?rq=1). Second, I want to keep only those observations in the **at least five consecutive row** of `id` selected by first step. The ideal result would be :

```
df
  id time
1  1 2000
2  1 2001
3  1 2002
4  1 2003
5  1 2004
```

I could write a complex function using for loop and `diff` function, but this may be very time consuming both in writing the function and getting the result if I have a bigger data set with lots if `id`. But this is not seems like R and I do believe there should be a one or two line solution.

Anyone know how to achieve this? your time and knowledge would be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, I want it to be numeric @bouncyball

Comment: I copy your code and rerun it, there is just # A tibble: 0 x 3
# Groups:   id, grp [0]
# ... with 3 variables: id <fctr>, time <dbl>, grp <dbl> , am I missing something important? not familiar with `tidyr`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` to group by `id` and consecutive time, and `filter` groups with less than 5 entries, i.e.

```
#read data with stringsAsFactors = FALSE
df<-data.frame('id'=c('1','1','1','1','1','1','1'),
               'time'=c('1998','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2007'), 
                                                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(time = as.integer(time)) %>% 
 group_by(id, grp = cumsum(c(1, diff(time) != 1))) %>% 
 filter(n() >= 5)
```

which gives

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 3
> # Groups:   id, grp [1]
>      id  time   grp
>   <chr> <int> <dbl>
> 1     1  2000     2
> 2     1  2001     2
> 3     1  2002     2
> 4     1  2003     2
> 5     1  2004     2
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @Sotos answer, this solution instead uses `seqle` (from `cgwtools`) as the grouping variable:

```
library(dplyr)
library(cgwtools)

df %>% 
  mutate(time = as.numeric(time)) %>%
  group_by(id, consec = rep(seqle(time)$length, seqle(time)$length)) %>%
  filter(consec >= 5)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   id, consec [1]
     id  time consec
  <chr> <dbl>  <int>
1     1  2000      5
2     1  2001      5
3     1  2002      5
4     1  2003      5
5     1  2004      5
```

To remove grouping variable:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(time = as.numeric(time)) %>%
  group_by(id, consec = rep(seqle(time)$length, seqle(time)$length)) %>%
  filter(consec >= 5) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-consec)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
     id  time
  <chr> <dbl>
1     1  2000
2     1  2001
3     1  2002
4     1  2003
5     1  2004
```

**Data:**

```
df<-data.frame('id'=c('1','1','1','1','1','1','1'),
               'time'=c('1998','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2007'),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that on your data:

```
df[,] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))

IND1 <- (df$time - c(df$time[-1],df$time[length(df$time)-1])) %>% abs(.)
IND2 <- (df$time - c(df$time[2],df$time[-(length(df$time))])) %>% abs(.)

df <- df[IND1 %in% 1 | IND2 %in% 1,]

df[ave(df$time, df$id, FUN = length) >= 5, ]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but from my understanding, you are using the information that the starting and ending point of the consecutive row is known, which is not the case in my real problem.

Comment: have you tried my code? It should also work when values are missing (NA)

Comment: @JasonGoal Please then provide reproducible code that matches your actual data.

Comment: of course I did, others work good except this line : `df <- df[IND1 %in% 1 | IND2 %in% 1,]` only the first condition would be applied. With all due respect but the problem here is not about reproducible code, its about your solution is hard coded base on know the staring and ending points ex ante. What I mean about not the real problem is that with another `id`, specific time and position in the `time` vector will change then your code won't apply any more.

Answer (score 0):

A solution from `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `data.table`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(time = as.numeric(as.character(time))) %>%
  arrange(id, time) %>%
  right_join(data_frame(time = full_seq(.$time, 1)), by = "time") %>%
  mutate(RunID = rleid(id)) %>%
  group_by(RunID) %>%
  filter(n() >= 5, !is.na(id)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-RunID)
df2
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      id  time
  <fctr> <dbl>
1      1  2000
2      1  2001
3      1  2002
4      1  2003
5      1  2004
```