# Keep only consecutive monthly, atleast x months of data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, panel-data, date-difference

I have a data.frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(cik = c(1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800,1800), date = c('2000/01/01','2000/02/01','2000/03/01','2000/04/01','2000/05/01','2000/06/01','2007/02/01','2007/02/01','2009/03/01','2009/04/01','2018/05/01','2018/06/01','2018/07/01','2018/08/01','2018/09/01'), value = c(2,1,3,6,5,4,7,5,9,3,9,8,7,6,8))
df <- df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(date, formate="%Y/%m/%d"))

df
cik     date        value
1800    2000-01-01  2       
1800    2000-02-01  1       
1800    2000-03-01  3       
1800    2000-04-01  6       
1800    2000-05-01  5       
1800    2000-06-01  4       
1800    2007-02-01  7       
1800    2007-02-01  5       
1800    2009-03-01  9       
1800    2009-04-01  3       
1800    2018-05-01  9       
1800    2018-06-01  8       
1800    2018-07-01  7       
1800    2018-08-01  6       
1800    2018-09-01  8
```

This is a panel dataset so there are more cik, this is just to illustrate.

I want to have two things done to this data set. First I want to find all the `cik` that have at least 5 consecutive observation (in my real data set I want at least 24 consecutive observations, but the 5 is just for illustration purposes. And then secondly I want to keep all the rows which are part of the 24 consecutive observation. So the end result I want is this:

```
df
cik     date        value
1800    2000-01-01  2       
1800    2000-02-01  1       
1800    2000-03-01  3       
1800    2000-04-01  6       
1800    2000-05-01  5       
1800    2000-06-01  4           
1800    2018-05-01  9       
1800    2018-06-01  8       
1800    2018-07-01  7       
1800    2018-08-01  6       
1800    2018-09-01  8
```

I have attempted the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46646537/keep-only-consecutive-observations), with a combination of other post however couldn't find the answer. It seems when I convert to yearmonth the previous solution no longer works, any help would be appreciatied. Thank in advance!

Comment: welcome to SO. I suggest to revise the question because its unclear, Your desired output is the same as the input, excluding the years 2007 and 2009. Why are these two years excluded from the desired output? Besides this, also show what you've tried (i.e. the code) even if its incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You were already quite on the right track with the answer you referred to.
All that was missing is to parse the date with `lubridate::ydm` before throwing it into the `diff` function.
Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(
    date = ydm(date)
  ) %>%
  arrange(cik, date) %>%
  group_by(cik, grp = cumsum(c(1, diff(date) > 1))) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(date) >= 5) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
```

`grp` will put your data in blocks of sequential dates. By increasing the `cumsum` only on `diff > 1`, the above solution is also robust to your specific case where more than one observation per date & cik seem to be allowed (such as on "2007-02-01").
However, I also adapted the filter, so that it does rule out a group if it doesn't have at least 5 *different* dates (using `n_distinct(date)` instead of simply `n()`), meaning you are sure to have a window of at least 5 days.
It would then be up to you how to treat duplicate observations in your window...